# Triggers: Page is unavailable in Personal Workspace

Tags: ui-automation, restriction, rpa, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I'm trying to schedule a ui path task in the orchestrator. But I get this error of restricted access at the triggers section

I'm using the enterprise trial version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like only in the community edition or the enterprise edition it's available.